# echo esc_url( get_permalink($post->ID) + complete the ID's url

Tags: php, id

I am in a deep trouble

I try to only display the content of a post after clicking a bouton in order to not have the header and the footer again. 
Manually I have downloaded the plugin "Show Content Only" that allow me to do that: http://myurl.com/mypost**&content-only=1**

My problem is that I would like to automatize the process.
I have a php structure that is: `echo esc_url( get_permalink($post->ID)`

So my question is can I add something after the `$post->ID` to display the whole url with `&content-only=1`? Or is there an other way more simple.

Thank you very much.

Cheers from France !

Comment: `echo esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '&content-only=1' );` should get you the URL you're looking for. But how to "automate" inserting this will depend on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach, from my point of view, is to use [`add_query_arg()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/):

```
$only_conent_url = add_query_arg( array( 'content-only' => 1 ), get_permalink( $post->ID ) );
```

And then you can escape it if you need:

```
esc_url( $only_conent_url );
```

`add_query_arg()` takes the URL passed as second paramenter and append a properly formatted query string built from the key=>value pairs contained in the array passed as first argument.